# Annotate new field with the same name as existing one

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-orm

We are facing a situation here that I would like to get more experienced user’s opinion. We are at Django 4, Python 3.9.

The current scenario:

We already have our system running in production for a reasonable time and we need to change on the Backend some returned data to our Frontend application (Web, mobile…) based on users choice.

Something important is: **Changes on the Frontend side are not an option for now.**

We need to override some attributes from one model, based on existing or not corresponding data on another table.

The Tables (Django Models):

AgentSearch (this data is replaced every single day by an ETL process)

- id
- identifier_number (unique)
- member_first_name
- member_last_name
- member_email
- some_other_attrbs

Agent (Optional data that the agent can define)

- id
- agent_search_identifier_number (FK OneToOne)
- first_name
- last_name
- email

For our requirement now, all the queryset will be made starting on `AgentSearch`. The idea is getting the `Agent` data instead of `AgentSearch` data every time there is an agent linked to it.

Today we get like this:

`AgentSearch.objects.all()`

I know that would be easier to annotate new columns like this:

```
        # using a different attribute name
        NEW_member_first_name=Case(
            When(
                agent__id__isnull=True,
                then=F("member_first_name"),
            ),
            default=F("agent__first_name"),
        ),
```

This would require us to make changes on the FrontEnd.

If we try:

```
        # using the same attribute name
        member_first_name=Case(
            When(
                agent__id__isnull=True,
                then=F("member_first_name"),
            ),
            default=F("agent__first_name"),
        ),
```

Django will throw:

```
`ValueError Exception saying: The annotation 'member_first_name' conflicts with a field on the model.`
```

We already tried removing the "overridable" attributes from the base query. Example:

```
        # Tell Django ORM to not get the column from DB
        AgentSearch.objects.all().defer('member_first_name')
        .annotate(
             member_first_name=Case(
                 When(
                     agent__id__isnull=True,
                     then=F("member_first_name"),
                 ),
                 default=F("agent__first_name"),
             ),
```

Still:

```
`ValueError Exception saying: The annotation 'member_first_name' conflicts with a field on the model.`
```

Also tried forcing the values only for non "overridable" attributes from the base query. Example:

```
        # Tell Django ORM to not get the column from DB
        AgentSearch.objects.all().values('some_other_attrbs')
        .annotate(
             member_first_name=Case(
                 When(
                     agent__id__isnull=True,
                     then=F("member_first_name"),
                 ),
                 default=F("agent__first_name"),
             ),
```

Still:

```
`ValueError Exception saying: The annotation 'member_first_name' conflicts with a field on the model.`
```

Also I give a try creating a django context manager to do this, but it would throw the same error.

In your opinion, what would be an elegant way to do this?  We found a solution, but seems really ugly.

How it can work for now:

```
class BaseAgentSearch(AbstractBaseModel):
    ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AgentSearch(BaseAgentSearch):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "app_agentsearch"
        # setting to false, since this model will act only as a "reader"
        managed = False
    ###########################################################
    # Original DB columns are mapped to a temp_ attribute name
    ###########################################################
    temp_member_first_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, db_column="member_first_name"
    )
    temp_member_last_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, db_column="member_last_name"
    )
    temp_member_email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=64, blank=True, db_column="member_email"
    )


class AgentSearchWrite(BaseAgentSearch):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "app_agentsearch"

    member_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    member_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    member_email = models.EmailField(max_length=64, blank=True)
```

Then Query as:

```
    AgentSearch.objects.all()
    .annotate(
        member_first_name=Case(
            When(
                agent__id__isnull=True,
                then=F("temp_member_first_name"),
            ),
            default=F("agent__first_name"),
        ),
        member_last_name=Case(
            When(agent__id__isnull=True, then=F("temp_member_last_name")),
            default=F("agent__last_name"),
        ),
        member_email=Case(
            When(agent__id__isnull=True, then=F("temp_member_email")),
            default=F("agent__email"),
        ),
```

This works as expected. But seems really strange and ugly. And also, to add/update data, we should now use the `AgentSearchWrite` model that have the correct columns on DB and model.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was using the `SerializerMethodField`, but that might cause your join on `Agent` and `AgentSearch` to happen multiple times for a single row.